# Cannot access .length property of dynamic array in Solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays

I have a mapping like below.

```
struct A {
  //Some fields
}

mapping(address => A[]) testMapping;
```

When I add a new item to that array, I can use the code below and it works well.

```
testMapping[msg.sender].push()
```

In some code, I am also clearing this array like this.

```
delete testMapping[msg.sender]
```

After clearing, when I try to access `length` property of this array, it reverts the execution.
This also happens when I try to access `length` property before adding any element to array.

The only thing that comes to my mind is when clearing the array setting `length` property to `0` like below.

```
testMapping[msg.sender].length = 0
```

But in after Solidity v0.6.0, `length` property became read-only, so this is not working as well.

Why this is happening, I could not find a solution online and in Solidity docs.